# Is it possible to use Vagrant with intelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, vagrant

Let's say I'm working with Java and using IntelliJ to do things like build and deploy and other things like that.

I haven't used Vagrant before, but is it possible to keep using IntelliJ for the building and deployment while running a Vagrant instance?

Comment: In general it would say yes as long as you don't go into details how you exactly do building/deployment

Comment: Of course you can, basically vagrant is just a set of virtual machines that you can use for development (build, test, deploy etc...). It doesn't affect your host OS at all, including your IDE.

Comment: Is there any way to build and deploy with IntelliJ, or does that all have to be done via the command-line?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can use your IDE with Vagrant. I just spent a lot of time thinking about how to do this and answering a similar question, hopefully this gives you some context.

[Vagrant for a Java project: should you compile in the VM or on the host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625421/vagrant-for-a-java-project-should-you-compile-in-the-vm-or-on-the-host)

With the VM on a private network, you can deploy a WAR to a running web server as you would any remote server. Alternatively, from inside the VM you can symlink the webapps folder to the compile target on your host, eliminating the need to build a WAR and redeploy explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a `NFS` shared directory in your vagrant and then you can access it both in your localhost and the vagrant box.

Just add this line to your `Vagrantfile` and then execute `vagrant reload`:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "shared", "/home/vagrant/shared", type: "nfs" ,  mount_options: ['rw', 'vers=3', 'tcp', 'fsc' ,'actimeo=2']
```

You can find the `shared` directory in the same folder as your `Vagrantfile`